# APNS not working overnight

Tags: ios, iphone, heroku, apple-push-notifications, javaapns

I used to send notifications to iOS phones through my server.

My APNS certificate hasn't changed since December 2014, and is still valid.

However, I get, since yesterday, this error when the server tries to send any APNS notifications:

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
```

What could be the reason? Since I strictly didn't change my backend (no delivery) and it worked yesterday...

May it be a temporary bug regarding APNS server?

Comment: Are you sure the certificate hasn't expired?  If it was generated in late November 2014 it would be expired now

Comment: That s exactly what I thought now. Actually, I was generating new certificates few months ago, but not using them for APNS since the "old" was valid. That would explain why I don t receive any mails from Apple if my actual certificate has expired. Will try to refresh it now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @PaulW11 evokes, the reason was that the APNS certificate expired the 19th november 2015.

I've just renewed the APNS certificate and the whole well works now.